# Moving object's direction and keeping it reversed for x period of time using keys

Tags: processing

Before I had a question regarding Arduino and its sensors but to make it simpler to understand my question I have created an example using a keypress.

So the idea is for my Arduino project I have a sensor that activates and when it does I want a paddle to move in a direction lets say for for seconds. In my arduino project I will be running an if statement and if that if statement is no longer true the object will stop doing that command even if the four second move isn't done yet.

Instead of Arduino sensors lets simplify this with a keypress. When the key is pressed I want the ball to move in the direction for four seconds. I need a way to say that if the keypress is activated even when it ends to continue movement. I know I might need to use a boolean and a timer to do so but I am unsure how to. (Note: It is important I do not want something like a key hold or like a mouse hold I want a key press because it more closely resembles the sensor I am using)

Here is an example code (I am not using this code by any means but I think it is good for someone helping me with what I am trying to figure out):

```
int ballX;
int ballY;
int radius;
int ballSpeed;

void setup()
{
 size(600, 600);
 background(255, 255, 255);
 smooth();
 frameRate(60);

 ballX = width/2;
 ballY = height/2;
 radius = 15;
 ballSpeed = 8;

}

void draw()
{
  fill(255, 255, 255, 50);
  noStroke();
  rect(0, 0, width, height);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(ballX, ballY, radius*2, radius*2); 
}


void keyPressed()
{
  if ( (keyCode == LEFT) && (ballX > radius) )
  {
    ballX = ballX - ballSpeed;
  }

}
```

Comment: Do a search of `frameCount` or `millis()` in the [tag:processing] tag for a ton of results. If you still can't get it working, please narrow your problem down to a [mcve] that uses the arrow keys instead of an Arduino, that way we can run your code on our computers.

Comment: @KevinWorkman here's the issue the sensor is like a keypress in a way. If I want to make an object move a certain direction for lets say 5 seconds I could very easily do so using lerp() and a keypress to activate it. This sensor takes what is in front of it and that makes the if statement true right? So as soon as one takes their hand away the if statement is no longer true and the object will no longer continue the movement lets say using lerp(). I need something more like if the if statement is activated and it is then deactivated (hand moved away) to still continue its path until time ends

Comment: @KevinWorkman an if statement is only true well IF its true but all I need to know is how I can possibly take an if statement to activate a movement and keep it there even if the conditions are no longer true until time ends and then have it resume normal motion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want one or more separate variables for this. Something like:

```java
boolean moving = false; // is the ball moving
int moveUntilTime = -1; // time when it should stop

void draw()
{
  fill(255, 255, 255, 50);
  noStroke();
  rect(0, 0, width, height);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(ballX, ballY, radius*2, radius*2); 

  if (moving == true) {
     if (millis() < moveUntilTime) {
       ballX = ballX - ballSpeed;
     }
     else {
       moving = false;
     }
  }
}

void keyPressed()
{
  if ( (keyCode == LEFT) && (ballX > radius) )
  {
    moving = true;
    moveUntilTime = millis() + 5000; // move for 5 seconds
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully, and as a quick note I ended up adding lerp to the ballX position this way not only does it stop doing the action over 5 seconds but during those 5 seconds I have lerp moving it a very specific distance.